# Convert J2C(Jpeg 2000) image to JPEG

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-conversion

I have a bunch of images in Jpeg 2000 format(J2C). I need to display that images in browser and therefore I have to convert these images to simple JPEG format. I am wondering if C# has some built mechanisms to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/). Don't think c# has built-in support for JP2

Comment: Yes, that library fits my needs. The only problem is that free image uses PInvoke

Comment: You can try [Jpeg2000.Net library](https://bitmiracle.com/jpeg2000/) to avoid PInvoke. Here is basic sample for Jpeg2000 decoding: https://github.com/BitMiracle/Jpeg2k.Samples/blob/master/Samples/DecodeJpeg2000/C%23/DecodeJpeg2000.cs. Disclaimer: I am working on this library, the library is commercial.